# Render is working locally, but not on the server

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, particles

I'm looking for some advice. I currently am using AWS GPU instances for my rendering. It has worked well until now.

I have a scene that is a particle system inside a smoke domain to behave as a sort of smoke. My laptop will render the particles fine, but the server just refuses to render them.

Any reason that might be? Anything I should know about particles/point density textures that might cause them to render badly on the server?

Comment: Simulations need to be cached. Set your project to use relative folders. Bake the simulation to disk on your local computer, upload the cache folder along with the blend file to the server.

Comment: Ah, I thought they were baked into the blend file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The blend file doesn't save a lot of things into it: images used as textures (unless packed), simulations caches (smoke, particles, physics) or video files.

Simulations need to be cached to disk and made available on the remote computer.

Set your project to use relative folders. Bake the simulation to disk on your local computer, upload the cache folder along with the blend file to the server.

Just like cached simulations, all other "external" files need to be made available to the server when using remote rendering.

Comment: This was exactly it. Uploaded the cache folder with my blend file and all was well. Thanks!